# Catching object which is not subscriptable

Tags: python, object, error-handling, try-catch

I get the following error :"`TypeError: 'CustomObject' object is not subscriptable`".
This error occurs irregulary while working with custom objects, which are always created the same way. I'm wondering how to catch the object which is not `subscriptable` to get some further details?

The error doesn't give me any details by itself, like "NoneType" or anything else, which would be easy to check. From answers to kind of related questions, I found out that the error means, that a `__getitem__()` method doesn't exist. I'm wondering if it makes sense to do something like the following try-catch block to get the object information.

```
try:
    CustomObject.__getitem__()
except:
    print(CustomObject)
```

Or is there anything else I should keep in mind?
Thanks

Comment: Can you please post the code that produces the error?

Comment: I already fixed the error. I was trying to get an element over '__str()__' which didn't exist. But that's not the point, for future cases I would like to have something that catches the error and provides deeper insides if needed

Comment: An object not being subscriptable is enough information in itself - it means that it does not support the "getitem syntax", i.e. `my_custom_object[item]` where `item` is an arbitrary value. Lists and dictionaries are examples of subscriptable objects, accepting integers (lists) or hashables (dicts) as the `item`. If you encounter this error, it simply means that you should fix the syntax in the line that raised it (or alternatively, implement `__getitem__` so that your custom objects know how to deal with that syntax).